# Received many upvotes on other answers at the same time

Tags: support, moderation

I had answered a question here. Afterwards, I noticed that I received many upvotes for some of my other answers at the same time!

Where did these upvotes come from?

Comment: You've received a serial upvote from someone; it'll probably be reverted in the next 24 hours

Comment: Also see [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)

Comment: Could be once you answered that question the author looked at your profile and found your other content helpful.  It could be that you're also trying to get the meta effect on what you posted above, I hate that!

Comment: Question now is why is your answer completely deleted?

Comment: Samething seems to have happened on Feb 7; that one looks sock-puppetty

Comment: @JonH no man waht are you talking about :!!!!!!

Comment: yes now my answer and all the up vote were deleted !!

Comment: ...and the user

Comment: the question it self now was deleted !!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you explain please why the question and it's answer was removed too ?

Comment: @ZeRubeus Considering they've used an image of one of the SO mods in the question, I removed it.  The user was also a known troll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users (especially new ones) will occasionally upvote the *other* answers of a person that answered their question, especially if they felt is was exceptionally useful.

Unfortunately, they don't realize that this looks like (and really is) targeted voting, so the votes get reversed later. In general the behavior is well-intentioned though. Nothing for you to worry about.

Comment: Is there no time where it is acceptable to do so? I tend to upvote more than one answer to a question if I find the information provided useful...though I also do not notice those upvotes going away, so maybe those were deemed acceptable?

Comment: @Kimbluey Unless a single user posted a *lot* of answers to the same question (unlikely and suspicious if they did) then you aren't targeting votes towards a single user. Thus, they won't be reversed. The OP is talking about someone upvoting a bunch of his answers on presumably *different* posts, which is correctly interpreted as (well-intentioned) targeted voting.

Comment: Oh yes, duh! Thanks for the clarification. *I need more coffee...*